# Unable to append multiple videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

```js
function selectVideo() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var txt = [];
        if ('files' in x) {
            if (x.files.length == 0) {
                txt = "Select one or more files.";
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = x.files[i];
                    if ('name' in file) {
                        txt[i] = file.name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (x.value == "") {
                txt += "Select one or more files.";
            } else {
                alert("The files property is not supported by your browser!");
                console.log("The path of the selected file: " + x.value);
            }
        }

        console.log(txt); 

        for (var j = 0; j < txt.length; j++) {
            $("#chooseVideos").append(" <div id=\"vid" + j + "\" class=\"embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9\">");
            $("#vid" + j).append("<video width=\"320\" height=\"240\"> <source src=\"videos/" + txt[j] + "\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>");
        }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chooseVideos" class="container">
        <div id="choosevid">
            <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple onchange="selectVideo()" />
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to append multiple videos when they are selected by the user. I have a input file loader that the user will select which videos to upload to the site. All of this is working fine, and I'm saving the video file names into an array named txt. The problem is when I'm testing with just two videos, it only appends the video at txt[1]. Here is my code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < txt.length; j++) {       
    $("#demo").append("<video width=\"320\" height=\"240\"> <source src=\"videos/" + txt[j] + "\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>");
}
```

I even tried doing it using javascript instead of jquery like so:

```
for (var j = 0; j < txt.length; j++) {

      var video = document.createElement("video");
      video.src = "videos/" + txt[j];        

      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(video);
}
```

I want it to be able to append both the video at txt[0] and at txt[1], but it seems to default to the last element in the array and only appends the one. What am I doing wrong?

For reference, here is the html where I am attempting to append them:

```
<div id="chooseVideos" class="container">
    <div id="choosevid" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple onchange="selectVideo()" />
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of ```txt``` before you start the loop? Can you get ```console.log()``` to show the values you expect for ```txt[0]``` and ```txt[1]```?

Comment: For example, I am selecting two videos: coding.mp4 and computer.mp4. The value of txt before the loop is ["coding.mp4", "computer.mp4"].

Comment: Please submit a [mcve]. You can do so by [edit]ing your question and creating a stack snippet with the JavaScript and HTML you have, as well as initializing `txt` with the data you have in your program.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I believe I did that correctly. I kept the file uploader javascript in. For my testing purposes I would initialize txt to ["coding.mp4", "computer.mp4"]

Comment: Not that it would occur in any modern browser, but your else statement would append a `<video>` for each character in the error string you generated.

Comment: So.. you want people to view selected files as `<video>`? Is that your goal?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts exactly. The goal is to have the user select multiple videos and have them all appended as <video>. I also just changed the error output; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that uses various good practices to make code cleaner and more efficient.

For example, you don't have to check things like if a `File` contains a `name`, because it will always contain a `name`. Similarly, you'll almost never come across a browser now that doesn't support the `input[type="file"].files`, so it's relatively safe to assume that it will be there.

Feel free to post comments asking specific questions for clarification if anything below is unclear.

```js
$(function () {
  var $demo = $('#demo');
  var $temp = $('#video').children();
  var media = $temp[0];
  var $plce = $('#placeholder').children();

  $('#myFile').change(function () {
    var input = this;
    var files = input.files;
    var file, type;
    
    $demo.empty().each(function () {
      var src = $(this).find('source').attr('src');
      
      if (src) URL.revokeObjectURL(src);
    });
    
    if (files.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        type = file.type;
        
        if (media.canPlayType(type)) {
          $temp
            .clone()
            .appendTo($demo)
            .find('source')
            .attr({ type: type, src: URL.createObjectURL(file)});
        } else {
          $plce
            .clone()
            .appendTo($demo)
            .find('pre')
            .text(type);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $demo.text("No files selected");
    }
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}

#demo > * {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="template" id="video">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source />
  </video>
</div>
<div class="template" id="placeholder">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <span>Cannot play video of type: <pre></pre></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="chooseVideos" class="container">
  <div id="choosevid" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <input id="myFile" type="file" accept="video/*" multiple />
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. I'll mess around with this and I'll comment if I have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. The issue here is where I was trying to append the videos. I was trying to place both videos in the same `<div>` but I noticed it was in the `class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9`. This was placing the videos on top of each other, as it only allowed one responsive `<video>` to be seen. In the javascript I made sure to create a new `<div>` for each video:

```
for (var j = 0; j < txt.length; j++) {
        $("#chooseVideos").append(" <div id=\"vid" + j + "\" class=\"embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9\">");
        $("#vid" + j).append("<video width=\"320\" height=\"240\"> <source src=\"videos/" + txt[j] + "\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>");
    }
```

Works exactly how I want it to now.